# Regex in python trouble

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a text file that I would like to search through it to see how many of a certain word is in it. I'm getting the wrong count for the words. 
File is [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BtIGXAKAFpWRb8f2S1Emo1rRAKIR32Mp0hQsmeC5d8c/edit?usp=sharing)

code:

```
import re
with open('SysLog.txt', 'rt') as myfile:
for line in myfile:
    m = re.search('guest', line, re.M|re.I)

    if m is not None:
        m.group(0)

        print( "Found it.")
        print('Found',len(m.group()), m.group(),'s')




        break

for line in myfile:
    n = re.search('Worm', line)
    if n is not None:
        n.group(0)

        print("\n\tNext Match.")
        print('Found', len(n.group()), n.group(), 's')

        break

for line in myfile:
    o = re.search('anonymous', line)
    if o is not None:
        o.group(0)

        print("\n\tNext Match.")
        print('Found', len(o.group()), o.group(), 's')

        break
```

Comment: Why are you `break`ing after you've found one instance of the word?

Comment: Also, you're not counting anywhere in your code. And if you didn't `break` after a match, the first `for` loop would read through the entire file, leaving nothing to read for the following two loops.

Comment: You should also encase your word in `\b` if you want to ensure full word matches, otherwise you’ll match things like `Wormholes`

Comment: @ctwheels This is not necessary. If you look at the format of the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use a `regex`, you can use [`str.count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) to make the process much more simple:

```
with open('SysLog.txt', 'rt') as myfile:
    text = myfile.read()
    for word in ('guest', 'Worm', 'anonymous'):
        print("\n\tNext Match.")
        print('Found', text.count(word), word, 's')
```

To test this, I downloaded the `file` and ran the `code` above, and got the `output`:

```
    Next Match.
Found 4 guest s

    Next Match.
Found 91 Worm s

    Next Match.
Found 18 anonymous s
```

which is correct if you do a `find` on the `document` in a `text editor`!

**As a sidenote, I'm not sure why you want to print a `tab` (`\t`) before `'Next Match'` each time as it just looks weird in the output but it doesn't matter **:)***

Comment: I tried this but I get an error for the second print statement

Comment: I did have to update the answer as I missed something when testing it, please try again because it definitely works now (I literally just tested it)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code:

- `re.search` will only give you the first match, if any; this does not have to be a problem, though, as it seems like the word is only expected to appear once per line; otherwise, use `re.findall`
- the line `n.group(0)` does not do anything without an assignment
- `len(n.group())` does *not* give you the number of matches, but the length of the matched string
- you `break` after the first line in the file
- `myfile` is an iterator, so once the first `for line in myfile` loop has finished, the other two won't have any lines left to loop (it will never finish because of the `break` anyway, though)
- as already noted, you do not need regular expression at all

One (among many) possible ways of doing this would be this (not tested):

```
counts = {"worm": 0, "guest": 0, "anonymous": 0}
for line in myfile:
    for word in counts:
        if word in line:
            counts[word] += 1
```